# How to launch App Store app and navigate to developers page

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, itunes

I am trying to integrate **More Apps** button inside my app. When user press this, I want to navigate to App Store and open my developer's app page. Expecting to work iOS 8 and above. If anyone did this before, please give me solution. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by simply having the app open a link. Now this link depends on your developer account. I cannot tell you what your link will be. However, it will look something link this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/id(some id here)
```

Note that the id is NOT your developer team ID. I really don't know what this id is. You can find it by navigating to one of your apps on the website version of the App Store called iTunes Preview. Simply go to google and search up one of your app's names like so:

> AppName by Muzammil

Once you have opened this page, you will see the link "more by this developer". Click this, and copy the link of that page. Then you can just have your app open that link to show your list of apps on the App Store.

Here is the code to open a link just in case your need it:

```
let yourDeveloperURL = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/id(some id here)")!
UIApplication.shared.open(yourDeveloperURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Grayson. I already tried this but doesn't work. Will test more.